# Override CSS rule class:hover to use original rule value from class

Tags: css

Is it possible to cancel a class with hover rule so the rule uses the value from the class without the hover?

In this contrived example, my project has a stylesheet from a library that I've imported:

```css
/* library.css */
.listItem {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
}

.listItem:hover {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

In my app I don't want the border color to change on hover. I want the border color to stay the same.

```css
/* custom.css */
.listItem:hover {
 border-color: /* whatever value border-color is set to in .listItem */  
}
```

I know I could just set `border-color` in the custom.css example to green explicitly but I'm wondering if there is a more dynamic solution. I'm suspecting there isn't.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know your use case but one idea is to disable the hover using pointer-events:none but of course you will have 0 interaction for your element

Comment: I don't think there's a possiblity other than manually specifying a color override in your custom.css. There are 4 special keywords you can use as property values in CSS: `inherit`, `initial`, `unset` and the very new and largely unsupported `revert`, but I don't think they can achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you both for confirming my suspicions!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `!important`, than it will override everything but Javascript styles.

Here is your original example:

```css
.listItem {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
}

.listItem:hover {
  border-color: blue;
}

#div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "listItem" id = "div"></div>
```

And here is it with `!important`:

```css
.listItem {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green !important;
}

.listItem:hover {
  border-color: blue;
}

#div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "listItem" id = "div"></div>
```